# Psychological thriller in which the verse "My father was a penny" keeps recurring on a wall?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I dont recall much of that movie except that it was a psychological thriller, and a verse was scribbled on a dilapidated wall. In one scene, the villain impersonates a nurse and escapes from the lunatic asylum or some place where he was confined. I dont recall much else so am sorry for the vague details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the phrase that you're looking for is ***"My daddy is a dollar / I wrote it on a fence / My daddy is a dollar / not worth a hundred cents."***

I am pretty sure this is the movie because this is what the killer keeps on writing on the asylum. The movie is [In Dreams](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120710/) and I think its very much similiar to the type of the movie you mentioned about. It has the same scene where killer when he was a kid escapes the asylum in the disguise of a nurse who works there.

Here is the youtube [trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrRlBd0IDOo). Hoping this is the one you are seeking.

Comment: Perfect! That was the one I was looking for. With such vague details as I had given, it was really very clever of you to have got the right answer. Kudos!

Comment: @MamtaDalal I happened to have seen the movie a while ago. It would've been rather ambiguous to figure it out from scratch. :)